# pointers memory allocation using calloc example

Tags: pointers, memory, heap-memory, calloc

when the size of pointer array is itself 4 and when i try     to print 5th value it gives a random number.How? tell me how this random allocation happens. Thanks!

```
#include< stdio.h>   
#include< stdlib.h>

int main()
{
 int*    p_array;
 int i;
 // call calloc to allocate that appropriate number of bytes for the array
 p_array = (int *)calloc(4,sizeof(int));      // allocate 4 ints
 for(i=0; i < 4; i++) 
 {
  p_array[i] = 1;
 }
 for(i=0; i < 4; i++) 
 {
  printf("%d\n",p_array[i]);
 }
 printf("%d\n",p_array[5]); // when the size of pointer array is itself 4 and when i try to print 5th value it gives a random number.How?
 free(p_array);
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays start at zero, so `p_array[5]` wasn't initialized in your code. It is printing out a piece of memory that is somewhere on your system.

[Read this for a great description on why arrays are zero-based.](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html)

e.g.:

```
p_array[0] = 1;
p_array[1] = 1;
p_array[2] = 1;
p_array[3] = 1;
p_array[4] = 1;
p_array[5] = ?????;
```

Comment: what is that random number?

Comment: i would like to give you another code. please clarify my doubt.#include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>

 int main ()
 {
  int a,n;
  int * ptr_data;
  

  printf ("Enter amount: ");
  scanf ("%d",&a);
  int arr[a];
  ptr_data = (int*) malloc ( sizeof(int) );
  for ( n=0; n<a; n++ )
  {
   printf ("Enter number #%d: ",n);
   scanf ("%d",&ptr_data[n]);
  }
  
  for ( n=0; n<a; n++ )
   arr[n] = ptr_data[n]; //values in heap are copied to an array.
  printf("%d\n",sizeof(ptr_data));
  free (ptr_data);
  printf ("Output: ");
  for ( n=0; n<a; n++ )
   printf("%d\n",arr[n]);
  return 0;
 }

Comment: @bks4line I just ran your code and here's my explanation:

ptr_data is a pointer to a specific address on your machine, and therefore will always be of size 8. When you use: &ptr_data[n], you are actually getting the base address of ptr_data, and then adding to that address by n * type_size. e.g., &ptr_data[2] will be the value at the address of ptr_data + 2 * size_of_int.

Answer (score 0):

The following has [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) since you're reading past the end of the array:

```
p_array[5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%d\n",p_array[5]);
```

is an attempt to print an uninitialized section of memory, because your array `p_array` has the strenght to store only 5 items `p_array = (int *)calloc(4,sizeof(int));`  starting from 
`p_array[0]` through `p_array[4]` and hence `p_array[5]` gives you a garbage value.

Comment: is that a value in the heap?

Comment: @bks4line it need not to be specifically from heap, if that memory location happens to be in heap it could be the value from that heap loaction, what i want to say is, it is just a value on of that particular address